# unique constraint on table

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique-constraint, postgresql-9.6

I have the following table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE modules(
    id  integer PRIMARY KEY)

CREATE TABLE submodules(
    id          integer PRIMARY KEY,
    identnum    integer)

CREATE TABLE usablesubmodules(
    moduleid    integer REFERENCES modules(id),
    submoduleid integer REFERENCES submodules(id))
```

Basically a table of modules and a table of submodules. Modules can only use certain submodules as defined by the usablesubmodules table. How do I define a constraint such that the identnum values for the submodules usable by any given module are unique? That is, the following query must return a set of unique identnum values for any given moduleid 'x':

```
SELECT identnum FROM submodules
INNER JOIN usablesubmodules ON submodules.id = usablesubmodules.submoduleid
WHERE usablesubmodules.moduleid = x
```

I'm using postgresql 9.6 if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Set a uniqueness and `not null` contraint on `submodules.identnum`.

```
CREATE TABLE submodules(
    id          integer PRIMARY KEY,
    identnum    integer UNIQUE NOT NULL);
```

Create a composite PK on the `usablesubmodules` table.

```
CREATE TABLE usablesubmodules(
    moduleid    integer REFERENCES modules(id),
    submoduleid integer REFERENCES submodules(id)
    PRIMARY KEY (moduleid, submoduleid));
```

...or...

```
CREATE TABLE usablesubmodules(
    moduleid    integer REFERENCES modules(id),
    identnum    integer REFERENCES submodules(identnum)
    PRIMARY KEY (moduleid, identnum));
```

Either of the above will guarantee that you can never have an `identnum` associated to a module more than once.

The uniqueness constraint on `identnum` in the `submodules` table ensures that you will only ever have one `submodules` record for a given `identnum`.

The composite primary key on `usablesubmodules` ensures that you can never have more than one record with the same `moduleid` and `identnum`.

Comment: I have provided an updated answer that ensures uniqueness across the 2 tables.

Comment: `identnum` will not be unique in the submodules table. Submodule1 and Submodule 2 can have the same `identnum` as long as they are not usable by the same module.

Comment: In that case what you want is impossible - any attempt to create a constraint against the submodules table will be prone to a race condition because there could be concurrent writes occurring on that table.  Nothing prevents updating the record for submodule #2 to change its identnum, while another request is being made to link submodule #2 to a module that may already have a submodule with either the old or new identnum -- in either case you might get the wrong result because of the race condition.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have **two** constraints:

- {module,submodule} must be unique
- this pair must exist in allowed_pairs (where it also must be unique)

---

-- \i tmp.sql

```
CREATE TABLE modules(
        m_id integer PRIMARY KEY
        );

CREATE TABLE submodules(
        s_id integer PRIMARY KEY
        );

CREATE TABLE allowed_submodules(
        m_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES modules(m_id)
        , s_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES submodules(s_id)
        , PRIMARY KEY (m_id, s_id)
        );

CREATE TABLE used_submodules(
        m_id integer NOT NULL
        , s_id integer NOT NULL
        , PRIMARY KEY (m_id, s_id)
        ,  FOREIGN KEY (m_id,s_id) REFERENCES allowed_submodules(m_id,s_id)
        );
```

---

UPDATE: if you insist on keeping the (redundant, IMHO) additional key column `identnum`, here is how that could be added to the `used_submodules`table.

---

```
CREATE TABLE used_submodules(
        m_id integer NOT NULL
        , s_id integer NOT NULL
        ,  PRIMARY KEY (m_id, s_id)
        ,  FOREIGN KEY (m_id, s_id) REFERENCES allowed_submodules(m_id, s_id)
        , identnum integer NOT NULL
        ,  UNIQUE (m_id, identnum)
        );
```

Comment: This is not correct... you have ignored the variable identNum completely.

Comment: Maybe because it is redundant? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: It's not redundant. The `identnum` will uniquely identify the submodule in the scope of the module that can use it. For a given module all of it's submodules will have a unique `identnum`. Submodule1 and Submodule2 may have the same `identnum` as long as they are not usable by the same module. It's a bit of a weird system but I did not design the structure of the data this way. I just have to work with it.

Comment: If you insist on adding it: add it, and put a UNIQUE constraint on (module,identnum)` Do note that you are entering MVD-land here.

Comment: Can I add a constraint between a column in one table and a column in another table? ie. between modules.id and submodules.identnum?

Comment: No.  See my answer above about concurrency and race conditions.  You will have to handle this programmatically in the code.  You will need to do a check on every write (insert and update) to the usablesubmodules table *and* on every update to the submodules table to make sure that the identnum of a submodule isn't updated to one that is already associated to a specific module.  Then you will need to write code to handle the conflict - does the user want to dissociate one of the 2 submodules or cancel the update?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your input. It's much appreciated.